# Javers findChanges() method throws exception when used inside a method annotated with @Transactional

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javers

Javers findChanges() method throws exception when used inside a method annotated with @Transactional

org.polyjdbc.core.exception.QueryExecutionException: [SELECT_ERROR] Failed to run select query:
SELECT global_id_pk FROM jv_global_id WHERE local_id = ?  AND type_name = ?

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void test(Integer saId) {

    QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(saId,SomeClass.class).withChangedProperty(property);
    Changes changes = javers.findChanges(jqlQuery.build());
}
```

If I comment out the transactional annotation, everything works fine

Comment: please include the full error message including stack trace.

Comment: You are using very old version of Javers, probably older than 3.14.0, now have 5.8.5. You are supposed to check latest version of a library before reporting any bug.